# О современных планах изменения русского правописания

Tags: правила, реформа

В статье от 6 августа 2020 года написано следующее.

https://vz-ru.turbopages.org/s/vz.ru/news/2020/8/6/1053659.html?utm_source=turbo_turbo

Лингвист рассказал о назревших изменениях правил русского языка. В России будет создана **правительственная комиссия** по русскому языку, которая должна **«провести экспертизу правил русской орфографии и пунктуации».**

Например, **неурегулированным или не совсем логичным** можно назвать правило по написанию одной и двух «н», чередующихся гласных в корнях (рос – раст, плав – плыв и т. д.). Непонятно, почему это чередование нужно **учить ученикам**. Также отмечается, что необходимо решить вопрос **доступности русского языка** в регионах России, потому что есть такие, где почти 20% населения плохо им владеют.

Как вы относитесь к подобным перспективам?

Действительно ли могут осуществиться такие планы или вряд ли они будут успешными?

Comment: безусловно, в русском языке правила требуют редакции. Но вопрос этот не такой уж легкий. Вы же сами это понимаете.

Comment: Конечно, правила требуют редакции, и вопрос нелегкий. Но вот занимаются ли  наши лингвисты этим вопросом, есть ли какие-то конкретные планы и принципиальные решения - вот что интересно.

Comment: Да, занимается орфографическая комиссия. Но она собирается крайне редко. Не так уж и легко поменять устоявшиеся написания. Вы же помните, что из этого вышло, когда специалисты в главе Лопатина предлагали изменения.

Answer (score 2):

Это пока не ответ, а **комментарий к вопросу**

Вот опять  мой вопрос не вызвал интереса, и, вероятно, мне **надо научиться задавать интересные вопросы**. Прежде всего, надо разобраться, **что такое "интерес"** и как он возникает. Ведь слово «интерес»  само по себе интересно.

Значение

**ИНТЕРЕС**  1. Внимание, любопытство.  2. Важность, значение; привлекательность.  3. обычно мн.: У него нет никаких интересов. 4. Разг. Корысть, выгода; польза.  У меня здесь свой и.

Этимология

**ИНТЕРЕС**  Заимств. в Петровскую эпоху из нем. яз. сущ. интерес < Interesse, восходящего к лат. interesse «важное значение» < «иметь важное значение». Исходное значение — «полезный, выгодный», значение «занимательный, увлекательный» вторично.

Итак,  в современном языке **внимание и любопытство** – это самое важное, но **польза** тоже не исключается (это как бы **мотивация** для знания чего-либо).

А вот для  любопытства можно  обозначить **три ситуации:**

а) неинтересно, когда ничего не знаешь; б) неинтересно, когда всё знаешь; в) интересно, когда знание **неполное** (желательно в соответствии с золотым сечением),  но при этом дополнительно должна быть **интрига**.

Вот я и попробую оценить интерес к своему вопросу и делаю такие **выводы**.

(1) Мотивация может быть у **педагогов, писателей и работников печати** (редакторов, издателей), но их здесь мало.

(2) С точки зрения любопытства, знание  участниками  этой темы, вероятно,  соответствует среднему положению, но вот **интриги они не чувствуют**. Может быть, надо это как-то обозначать?

У меня есть мотивация,  но не об этом речь. Эта тема для меня **занимательна и с точки зрения интриги.** Вот наши  реформаторы собираются улучшить систему письма. Они делают это исключительно из благих намерений, кроме того, у них есть на это **полномочия.**

**А вот получится ли у них выполнить задуманное?** А вдруг наша Система письма вообще "неисправляемая", вдруг она окажет им достойное сопротивление? Возможно ли такое – вот в чем можно увидеть **интригу**.

Теперь я надеюсь, что интерес к теме обязательно появится.

Comment: Sharon, ничего из этого не получится. И лингвисты по этому поводу уже высказались.

Comment: Серж,  а какие у них были доводы, ведь это не всем очевидно. И почему мнение лингвистов не учитывается людьми, которые собираются  проводить экспертизу правил. И другой вопрос к лингвистам: у них есть предложения по решению этой проблемы. Ведь действительно даже носителям языка сложно освоить грамотное письмо, а другим людям тем более. Мы же все-таки заинтересованы в том, чтобы  русский язык был востребованным, чтобы  наша культура была известна во всем мире.

Comment: Хотел я написать второй ответ, но решил пока ограничиться комментариями. Значит так. Я внимательно ознакомился с поручением Мишустина с мнением лингвистов (возможно тех же, на которых ссылается Серж) и могу сказать следующее. Ничего из того, что Sharon ждет от этой комиссии не получится по той простой причине, что эта комиссия не ставит перед собой цели какой-то реальной реформы. Её, комиссии цель, цель чисто аппаратная, наподобие той, что веками была охвачена всякого рода "прожектами о введении единомыслия в России". Конкретно по унификации правил - не ставят они себе такой цели.

Comment: Они всего лишь хотят вытроить в шеренгу авторов всех пособий и словарей - и заставить их шагать в ногу. То есть выработать некий "Устав филологической службы" - и излагать всё во всех пособиях исключительно по "Уставу" - не столько даже по сути, сколько по форме. Это  не реформа, скорее наоборот, консервация. Аналогично и со всем остальным, упомянутым в стартовом посте. В этой ситуации предельно понятно, почему на буруне этой грязноватой волны оказались именно "пушкари" - известные оппоненты всей академической науки. А "академиков", естественно, никто не спросил. И не собирается.

Comment: Вот как-то так. А г-н Осадчий или лукавит, или просто не в курсе.

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересная информация. Любопытно будет, что они там придумают и придумают ли вообще.

Comment: Sharon, почитайте эту статью.  https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fnewtimes.ru%2Farticles%2Fdetail%2F191579%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR1gkLA0SbnSxNI9ITaULIO-dlxtKncrvioCdowFo1ImQZ5uBEw-HMsWo68&h=AT0wtUK41ZKuN6UKKGleiX4S2TLMgi266hlJqjCxXwFXpVNUb0Wd0d2ad590OgzzoWu9l1NjdW_20ciy8hD-33JIXlNeRZKF3WRpPtwsGYsGyKfO4tngozrH3xAiu-q-9gE&__tn__=%2CmH-R&c[0]=AT0y7nENU8VLKrA4q4Z2bZ-Wr-JwGdw5tHuzxZsS9KxNcBPNFxcsfYK4uEd9hUXpHV335408oXvSVlWS-qeWk3mWr5XOW_BAfBlZDJpYUjSBNpHplUTbX6Qp_cxTBfK_Ri77mmmPMDizYleXfRvg

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, любопытно. Сразу появился интерес к поправкам, надо будет почитать. А кто готовил окончательную редакцию текста?

Comment: @Sharon, о какой редакции текста идет речь?

Comment: Sharon, простите.Я не ту ссылку дал вам. Вот та ссылка, которую хотел дать. https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=3051827674916125&id=100002667666453

Comment: Да, Серж, спасибо, прочитаю обязательно.

Comment: @Серж Да, мистика какая-то, даже не верится, что всё это случайные совпадения. Я сначала думала, что статью написал эзотерик-философ, но оказалось, что вполне серьезный ученый-материалист.

Answer (score 1):

Sharon, вы меня извините, конечно, но тут и обсуждать нечего. Обычная сплетня от агентства ОБС.
Если что-то такое действительно зашевелилось, то я хочу видеть не поток журналистского сознания и даже не ссылку на г-на Осадчего, известного широкой публике разве что в качестве большого специалиста в области русского мата, а четкого пояснения минимум по двум моментам.

1. Зачем нужна ещё какая-то комиссия, если есть понятного статуса Орфографическая Комиссия РАН, ныне руководимая весьма уважаемым А.Д. Шмёлевым, а ранее - не менее уважаемым В. В. Лопатиным?
2. Что нового собирается предлагать создаваемая комиссия в сравнении с редакцией правил 2002 г., разработанной упомянутой ОК под руководством Лопатина? Вопрос не праздный, все эти **рост/раст** и **н/нн в причастиях** там, в Предложениях-2002, детальнейшим образом обработаны, но положены на полку, поскольку как норма никем не кодифицированы и де-юре имеют неопределенный статус.

Ну и довеском, при чем тут вообще Пушкинский Институт, о котором до феерического выступления его ректорши Русецкой с верноподданнейшим оправданием грубейшего стилистического, если не грамматического, ляпа (в бюллетене голосования *по поправкам в Конституции*) никто ничего толком и не слышал со времен Костомарова?

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, но определенные факты существуют. Президент дал поручение, Мишустин должен его выполнить.  Поэтому можно думать, зачем нужна такая комиссия, но если сказали ее создать, значит, вероятно, создадут что-то. К примеру, приводится такое цитирование: Мишустин сказал на заседании кабинета министров, что «одним из важнейших вопросов сегодняшней повестки является создание правительственной комиссии по русскому языку», передает ТАСС. Также «необходимо провести экспертизу правил русской орфографии и пунктуации».

Comment: *сказали ее создать, значит, вероятно, создадут что-то* - вот когда создадут, тогда и будем думать, что они этакого создали. Или хотя бы сам Мишустин поймет, что именно ему велели создать - и нам расскажет. Сам расскажет, а не со слов Осадчего. Кстати говоря, иом знакомые в ОК Шмелева пока ничего о некой конкурирующей организации не знают.

Comment: Мне кажется, что неплохо и заранее подумать, Меня чисто теоретически интересует вопросы:  можно ли с помощью каких-либо реформ повысить всеобщую грамотность, а также можно ли нанести Системе русского письма значительный урон какими-то неумелыми действиями.

Comment: И еще о высказывании Русецкой, я уже потом об этом думала. Да, это можно назвать грубейшим ляпом, но  так образованные люди подумают. Будут возмущаться, конечно, но их же меньшинство. А большинство должно было услышать простую истину: никакой ошибки не было.  Ни грамматической, ни стилистической. И они это услышали и успокоились. Это уже чистая политика, а не филология.

Answer (score 1):

**ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС**

1. Итак, у нас есть **Система письма**, на основе которой написана прекрасная классическая литература. По правилам этой же Системы пишется литература современная, ею пользуемся мы с вами. Это лучший выбор, который был сделан **за долгий путь развития**, просто подарок судьбы для нашего  языка. Она гибкая, совершенная, с ее помощью можно передать русскую речь со всеми ее оттенками;  также эта система способна к любому развитию, если **понимать ее законы**.
2. Но  люди, получившие филологическое образование и имеющие высокий статус, скорее всего, не понимают этого. Они **не отличают Систему письма от ее описания** (то есть от современной редакции правил), они  не понимают, что плоха методика обучения, а не сама Система. Им хочется  простоты, чтобы «учеников учить», им нужна всеобщая доступность.
3. Конечно, становится немного не по себе от таких планов, но есть надежда, что **язык сам защитит себя**. Сколько было этих попыток  реформировать правила, но все они закончились провалом. **Несколько орфографических тем всегда подвергались гонениям**. Реформаторам кажется, что дело только в Н и НН, да в чередующихся корнях, да в шипящих. Вот упростим эти правила – и все сразу **станут грамотными**.
4. **Как бы не так!**  В орфограмме Н и НН они, конечно же, введут единое написание для прилагательных и причастий, но это только часть темы, придется с ней смириться. Но там еще много чего ломать придется, не всё сведешь к единообразию. Орфограмма НЕ и НИ более сложна, к ней так просто не подступишься;  также  форму написания (слитно, раздельно, дефис) вряд ли можно привести к полному единообразию. Но это я назвала **сложные орфографические вопросы для пользователей**,  уже имеющих опыт грамотного письма.

А если вы только начинаете изучать русский язык, то непременно столкнетесь с проблемой **фонематической природы письма**: что-то можно писать по слуху, а какие-то звуки нужно проверять. Надо слышать эти звуки, знать, когда и как они изменяются, разбираться в русской графике. Многие слова с непроверяемыми  гласными придется выучить. Носители языка постепенно осваивают эту премудрость, а вот  для остальных это будет не так просто.

Таким образом, в орфографии можно изменить **только частные детали**, а людям кажется, что ее можно реформировать, упростить, сделать доступной.

4. **Но главное – это пунктуация**, вот что они не понимают. Без знания **грамматики** пунктуацию вообще не освоишь, но и это еще не всё. Пусть они очень хорошо почитают **Розенталя**, прежде чем реформировать правила: «*Особенности русской пунктуации — в многофункциональности знаков препинания и широкой их взаимозаменяемости, в своеобразии индивидуально-авторского использования знаков препинания, в гибкости пунктуационной системы, позволяющей выявлять не только смысловую сторону текста, но и стилистические его оттенки. Все это исключает формальный подход к соблюдению правил».*

Большинство вопросов на форуме связаны с **грамматикой, стилистикой, пунктуацией**. А именно такие знания отличают грамотного человека от не очень грамотного. Без труда и глубокого понимания языка к этой  крепости-невидимке так просто не подступишься.

А что у нас делается для того, чтобы сделать более эффективным обучение пунктуации? Почему бы не вспомнить про интонационный принцип. **Интонация** – это естественное **ритмико-мелодическое членение** речи,  которое **слышат все,** знаки же препинания в любом случае связаны с интонацией, хотя и неоднозначно.

Казалось бы, интонационный принцип должен изучаться и активно применяться на практике, но в новом справочнике под ред. Лопатина **об интонации не говорится практически ни слова** (у Розенталя информации больше). Но зато язык, по мнению  реформаторов, изучать стало проще.

Comment: Про интонационный принцип я не очень понял. Вы предлагаете подчинить правила этому принципу? Этот принцип, как вам известно, учитывается в русской пунктуации. Но он лишь он третьем месте.

Comment: Серж,  между этими принципами  не должно быть иерархии и распределения мест. Я могу предложить вам такое решение. Берете хороший современный справочник по синтаксису, там расписаны все грамматические модели, указана семантика отношений и даже интонация. Не хватает только объяснения уже расставленных знаков препинания. Но если мы знаем интонационную характеристику каждого знака, то дополнить  такой учебник несложно. И чем вам не Правила пунктуации, не хуже, чем у Розенталя. И всё на своих местах – семантика, грамматика, интонация. Никто не спорит, кто их них главнее.